# Why am I getting wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) for form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my `_search_box.html.erb` file

```
<%= form_tag "/search", :method => "get" do %>
  <%= text_field :q %> 
  <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

which is rendered in `search.html.erb`:

'search_box' %>

```
<% if @products %>
    <%= render(:partial => "products") %>
<% end %>
```

However, I am getting an error in `_search_box.html.erb`, line 2:

```
Showing /****/app/views/catalog/_search_box.html.erb where line #2 raised:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <%= form_tag "/search", :method => "get" do %>
2:   <%= text_field :q %> 
3:   <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
4: <% end %>
```

Waht's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `form_tag` that's giving you the error, it's `text_field`.  `text_field` is designed to be used inside `form_for`, not `form_tag`.

I think you mean to use `text_field_tag` instead.

**text_field(object_name, method, options = {})**

Returns an input tag of the “text” type tailored for accessing a specified attribute (identified by method) on an object assigned to the template (identified by object). Additional options on the input tag can be passed as a hash with options. These options will be tagged onto the HTML as an HTML element attribute as in the example shown.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

**text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})**

Creates a standard text field; use these text fields to input smaller chunks of text like a username or a search query.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html